# JSR 303 and property file

Tags: spring-mvc

If I'm using JavaBean Validation 1.0 (JSR 303), and I extract my validation messages into a property file how does Spring become aware of my property file? I know I need to declare a ResourceBundleMessageSource bean but I'm just not clear on how Spring/JavaBean validation becomes aware of this file?

Comment: I'm not sure, do you ask solely because you are interested (which is totally alright, of course) or do you have a problem applying that mechanism? If the latter, please post your configuration details and possible error messages.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm interested.  I have it working but I'm not clear as to how Spring comes to know about the property file.

Answer (score 0):

That is main idea of "Framework". It makes lots of magic/setups behind of scenes, so you don't have to write thousands rows of boilerplate code for every project. You can follow with default path/settings (messages.properties) or switch to something else using Configuraton or application.properties file (which also can be changed). But for sure, you don't want to do that in most cases, but you can.